# SpringBoot: How to store image/video files when using on-prem

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that receives data from user, the data contains images and videos.
I am a little skeptical about storing big files on database(MongoDb). As I can not use Amazon S3, what should I do to save images/videos ?

1. Should I save them in a folder in a docker on a VM? or
2. should I convert the image/video file to base64 and save it on MongoDb?
   in case 1) is a good option, what should be my implementation approach? I am new to this,
   i appreciate your comments.

I tried to save image/video files to database but it is extremely time consuming.

Comment: Databases might not be the correct place to store these data. File shsnte

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
What is File shsnte?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284321/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-any-kind-of-file-in-a-database-using-nosql-and-mon/72284711#72284711

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. It is recommended to store files in File Storage Systems. As you are not using S3 here, try if you can run a file storage server for this purpose.